# IPTables Exam Questions

Tags: networking, iptables

My prof has told me that our final exam will contain a couple questions on IPTables.  This is the first networking class offered at out university, but it is also a third year class.
I am wondering if people could help me think of some possible questions that he might ask.
We only have a half a page of notes on IPTables so the questions won't be very hard.  He just showed us some simple syntax of adding rules to the tables, like:

```
%iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p TCP -j ACCEPT
```

and so on, and ideas on what I should study?

Comment: if you vpn to your uni library and check past exam section for the networking module you may find some clues.
Around 50% of questions are just reworded question from previous exam papers and only the remaining 50% are questions invented for the exam.
I guess this is what most uni do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [iptables cheat sheet](http://www.unixnewbie.org/iptables-cheat-sheet/).

**If** you want more details, this might come in handy: [Quick HOWTO: iptables](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch14_%3a_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables).

Comment: Thank you, that is a great start.